# How to animate a number and reformat it (into K, M..etc) with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery to select several numbers from a page, load with animation, and then convert the number into easy to read format if it is too long.

I was able to make the animation effect and reformat work separately, but when I tried to combine them together, I have trouble doing that. Can someone help me understand what I did wrong, or is this possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<div class="stat-display__value">22200</div>
<div class="stat-display__value">338899</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.stat-display__value').each(function(){
  $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
     duration: 1000,
     easing: 'swing',
     step: function (now) {
           $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
  }
 });
 num = nFormatter($(this).text(), 2);
 $(this).html(num);
});

function nFormatter(num, digits) {
  const si = [
    { value: 1, symbol: "" },
    { value: 1E3, symbol: "K" },
    { value: 1E6, symbol: "M" },
    { value: 1E9, symbol: "G" },
    { value: 1E12, symbol: "T" },
    { value: 1E15, symbol: "P" },
    { value: 1E18, symbol: "E" }
  ];
  const rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  let i;
  for (i = si.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (num >= si[i].value) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
}
```

Here is the demo code on JS bin:
https://jsbin.com/ceqemag/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code only formats the number at runtime, which is then quickly overwritten by the `step` callback triggered by the `.animate()` method. You should be formatting the number in the `step` callback instead, i.e.:

```
step: function (now) {
    var formattedValue = nFormatter(Math.ceil(now), 2);
    $(this).text(formattedValue);
}
```

See proof-of-concept example below (or the [modified JSbin](https://jsbin.com/dapiconudi/edit?html,js,output)):

```js
$('.stat-display__value').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      var formattedValue = nFormatter(Math.ceil(now), 2);
      $(this).text(formattedValue);
    }
  });
});

//reformat numbers
function nFormatter(num, digits) {
  const si = [{
      value: 1,
      symbol: ""
    },
    {
      value: 1E3,
      symbol: "K"
    },
    {
      value: 1E6,
      symbol: "M"
    },
    {
      value: 1E9,
      symbol: "G"
    },
    {
      value: 1E12,
      symbol: "T"
    },
    {
      value: 1E15,
      symbol: "P"
    },
    {
      value: 1E18,
      symbol: "E"
    }
  ];
  const rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  let i;
  for (i = si.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (num >= si[i].value) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stat-display__value">22200</div>
<div class="stat-display__value">338899</div>
```